# Foursquare API oauth2 authorize invalid_request error

Tags: python, api, tornado, foursquare

I am building a python-tornado module for Foursquare oauth2. These are all the basic URLs setup:

```
_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token"
_OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL    = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authorize"
_OAUTH_AUTHENTICATE_URL = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate"
_BASE_URL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2"
```

This is the URL I am hitting, it is properly encoded and there's no unexpected characters inside redirect_uri:

https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fauth%2Ffoursquare%2Fconnect&client_id=my_client_id

And then I received the dreaded invalid_request page. There's no extra information, no error message.

I don't see any useful information under "net" tab inside Firebug as well.

So my question is:

- What can I do to debug this problem? Is there a flag I can set in the URL to receive more verbose error message?

#### TORNADO OAUTH2 BASE CLASS

```
class OAuth2Mixin(object):
    """Abstract implementation of OAuth v 2."""

    def authorize_redirect(self, redirect_uri=None, client_id=None,
                           client_secret=None, extra_params=None ):
        """Redirects the user to obtain OAuth authorization for this service.

        Some providers require that you register a Callback
        URL with your application. You should call this method to log the
        user in, and then call get_authenticated_user() in the handler
        you registered as your Callback URL to complete the authorization
        process.
        """
        args = {
            "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
            "client_id": client_id
        }
        if extra_params: args.update(extra_params)
        self.redirect(url_concat(self._OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL, args))

    def _oauth_request_token_url(self, redirect_uri= None, client_id = None,
                                 client_secret=None, code=None,
                                 extra_params=None):
        url = self._OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL
        args = dict(
            redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
            code=code,
            client_id=client_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
        )
        if extra_params: args.update(extra_params)
        return url_concat(url, args)   # url_concat is just a string utility that generates GET params given dictionary
```

#### FOURSQUARE MIXIN (THE ONE I AM CREATING)

```
import tornado.auth
from tornado import httpclient
from tornado import escape

class FoursquareMixin(tornado.auth.OAuth2Mixin):
    _OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token"
    _OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL    = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authorize"
    _OAUTH_AUTHENTICATE_URL = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate"
    _OAUTH_NO_CALLBACKS = False

    _BASE_URL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2"

    @property
    def httpclient_instance(self):
        return httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    def get_authenticated_user(self, redirect_uri, client_id, client_secret, code, callback):
        args = {
            "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
            "code": code,
            "client_id": client_id,
            "client_secret": client_secret,
        }

        self.httpclient_instance.fetch(
            self._oauth_request_token_url(**args),
            self.async_callback(self._on_access_token, redirect_uri, client_id, client_secret, callback)
        )


    def _on_access_token(self, redirect_uri, client_id, client_secret, callback, response):
        if response.error:
            logging.warning('Foursquare auth error: %s' % str(response))
            callback(None)
            return

        args = escape.parse_qs_bytes(escape.native_str(response.body))
        session = { "access_token": args["access_token"] }

        self.foursquare_request(
            path="/v2/users/self",
            callback=self.async_callback(self._on_get_user_info, callback, session),
            access_token=session["access_token"]
        )


    def _on_get_user_info(self, callback, session, user):
        if user is None:
            callback(None)
            return

        user.update({
            'first_name': user.get('firstName'),
            'last_name': user.get('lastName'),
            'home_city': user.get('homeCity'),
            'access_token': session['access_token']
        })
        callback(user)


    def foursquare_request(self, path, callback, access_token=None, post_args=None, **args):
        """
        If the request is a POST, post_args should be provided. Query
        string arguments should be given as keyword arguments.

        See: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/
        """
        url = self.__class__._BASE_URL + path

        all_args = {}
        if access_token:
            all_args["access_token"] = access_token
            all_args.update(args)
            all_args.update(post_args or {})

        if all_args: url += "?" + urllib.urlencode(all_args)

        callback = self.async_callback(self._on_foursquare_request, callback)
        if post_args is not None:
            self.httpclient_instance.fetch(url, method="POST", body=urllib.urlencode(post_args), callback=callback)
        else:
            self.httpclient_instance.fetch(url, callback=callback)


    def _on_foursquare_request(self, callback, response):
        if response.error:
            logging.warning("Error response %s fetching %s", response.error, response.request.url)
            callback(None)
            return
        callback(escape.json_decode(response.body))
```

Comment: And you've made sure that the redirect_url you're passing in is identical to the one you have specified at http://foursquare.com/oauth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing **response_type=code** on the authentication request.

Should look like:

[https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fauth%2Ffoursquare%2Fconnect&response_type=code&client_id=my_client_id](https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/auth/foursquare/connect&response_type=code&client_id=my_client_id)

I wrote a comprehensive 4sq Python library that handles the oauth2 dance for you. Might save you the trouble of writing your own, or give you implementation ideas if you're committed to your mixin architecture.

https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare

Here's the snippet that handles OAuth:

```
class OAuth(object):
    """Handles OAuth authentication procedures and helps retrieve tokens"""
    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.redirect_uri = redirect_uri

    def auth_url(self):
        """Gets the url a user needs to access to give up a user token"""
        data = {
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'response_type': u'code',
            'redirect_uri': self.redirect_uri,
        }
        return u'{AUTH_ENDPOINT}?{params}'.format(
            AUTH_ENDPOINT=AUTH_ENDPOINT,
            params=urllib.urlencode(data))

    def get_token(self, code):
        """Gets the auth token from a user's response"""
        if not code:
            log.error(u'Code not provided')
            return None
        data = {
            'client_id': self.client_id,
            'client_secret': self.client_secret,
            'grant_type': u'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri': self.redirect_uri,
            'code': unicode(code),
        }
        # Build the token uri to request
        url = u'{TOKEN_ENDPOINT}?{params}'.format(
            TOKEN_ENDPOINT=TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
            params=urllib.urlencode(data))
        log.debug(u'GET: {0}'.format(url))
        access_token = None
        # Get the response from the token uri and attempt to parse
        response = _request_with_retry(url)
        return response.get('access_token')
```